# calling drawRect in a UIView subclass

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I have subclassed a UIView and I have a drawRect implemented. I basically want this drawRect to be called after I've set the CGPoint, which is a property of this UIView. How do I do this?  Here's my code:

```
-(id) initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    if(self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder]) {
        point_.x = 0;
        self.page_ = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pages"];
    }
    return self;
}

// Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    if (point_.x != 0){
        [self.page_ drawInRect:rect];
        CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
        CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor blackColor].CGColor);
        CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 1.0f);
        CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 40, point_.y); 
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 420, point_.y);
        CGContextStrokePath(context);
    }
}
```

When I've set the point of this UIView and I call drawRect in my other UIViewController like follows:

```
 self.page_.point_ = CGPointMake(-100, self.title_.frameHeight + self.title_.frameX + 40);
    [self.page_ drawRect:self.page_.frame];
```

It gives me all of these errors:

```
  <Error>: CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0
    Feb 22 20:24:38 <Error>: CGContextSetBlendMode: invalid context 0x0
    Feb 22 20:24:38 <Error>: CGContextSetAlpha: invalid context 0x0
    Feb 22 20:24:38 <Error>: CGContextTranslateCTM: invalid context 0x0
    Feb 22 20:24:38 <Error>: CGContextScaleCTM: invalid context 0x0
    Feb 22 20:24:38 <Error>: CGContextDrawImage: invalid context 0x0
    Feb 22 20:24:38 <Error>: CGContextRestoreGState: invalid context 0x0
    Feb 22 20:24:38 <Error>: CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor: invalid context 0x0
    Feb 22 20:24:38 <Error>: CGContextSetLineWidth: invalid context 0x0
    Feb 22 20:24:38 <Error>: CGContextMoveToPoint: invalid context 0x0
    Feb 22 20:24:38 <Error>: CGContextAddLineToPoint: invalid context 0x0
    Feb 22 20:24:38 <Error>: CGContextDrawPath: invalid context 0x0
```

Why is this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***You should never, ever call `-drawRect:` directly.***

Use `-setNeedsDisplay` instead:

```
self.page_.point_ = CGPointMake(-100, self.title_.frameHeight + self.title_.frameX + 40);
[self.page_ setNeedsDisplay];
```

If you need to customize the drawing area (aka the `CGRect` that will be passed to `-drawRect:`), you can use `-setNeedsDisplayInRect:`

As [@rob mayoff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/77567/rob-mayoff) has suggested, you can override the setter for the `point_` property:

```
- (void)setPoint_:(CGPoint)point {
   if(!CGPointEqualToPoint(point_, point)) {
      point_ = point;
      [self setNeedsDisplay];
   }
}
```

Comment: It would be better to make the `point_` property setter call `setNeedsDisplay` if the value of `point_` has actually changed.

Comment: aha..that's a good idea.. so  in my setteer I would call setNeedsDisplay. Mind explaining why this is better?

Answer (score 2):

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder // (1)
{
if (self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder])
{
    [self setMultipleTouchEnabled:NO]; // (2)
    [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    [path setLineWidth:2.0]; 
}
return self;
}


- (void) drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 3.0);
CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathFillStroke);    //CGContextSetRGBFillColor doesn't work either
CGContextBeginPath(context);
CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 100.0, 60.0);
CGRect rectangle = {100.0, 60.0, 120.0, 120.0};
CGContextAddRect(context, rectangle);

CGContextStrokePath(context);
CGContextFillPath(context);
}
this code implement in create new uiview and add this code i hope that code you usefull.
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your drawing code into 
`UIGraphicsPushContext( context )`
and `UIGraphicsPopContext()` to avoid this error messages.